# Backbone + RequireJS - A Deferred that awaits the creation of another deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, jquery-deferred

I'm writing a Backbone + RequireJS project, and encountering the following situation:

**Module A:**

```
Backbone.Mediator.publish('ajax:fetch:in:module:b');

// I need to do something like **$.ajax(options).done()** here
```

**Module B:**

```
subscriptions: {
    'ajax:fetch:in:module:b': fetch
},

fetch: {
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

I've tried to hook `$.ajax(options)` under a shared namespace (like `cache.temp = $.ajax(options)`) in Module B, then calling `cache.temp.done()` inside Module A, but it happened way before `$.ajax(options)` was created so `cache.temp` was simply an `undefined`.

I guess one way to solve this problem is to create a deferred that delays the execution of the code before `$.ajax(options)` is ready, but am not very sure whether this is something doable. Or if there are better ideas around, I am all ears.

Comment: Did you set 'complete' callback in $.ajax settings?

Comment: Is the order of these request important or do you just need to know when both are done?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an simple example of requirejs working with jquery deferred:

**moduleA.js**

```
define(['require', 'jquery'], function(require, $) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    require(['moduleB'], function(moduleB) {
        deferred.resolve(moduleB);
    });

    return deferred.promise();

});
```

**app.js**

```
require(['moduleA'], function(deferred) {
    deferred.done(function(moduleA) {
        console.log(moduleA);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$.when` and `$.then` like this if you have a ajax or deferred obj.

`$.when( ajax call).then( do other thing)`